# stacked bar graph with log conversion of data or axis R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a horizontal stacked bar chart to visualize the transition between the best performing models over a range of values.  The point I'm having trouble with is that I would like my value axis (y initially, but I flip it to x with coord_flip()) to be a log scale such that 0.25 is my lower limit, 1 is in the middle, and 4 is my upper limit.  I want to maintain the correspondence between the transition between the models and the axis values.

Here is my data

```
stock.best<-c("ESTU","ESTU","ESTU","ESUM","ESUM","ESUM","SUMM","LLAT","LLAT","LLAT")
model.best<-c("D","T","Q","D","TQ","T","TQ","D","R","Q")
value.best<-c(1.18166,0.15034,2.668,0.6771123,1.408938,1.91395,4,0.2966743,1.143973,2.559352)
ALF.best<-data.frame(stock.best,model.best,value.best)
ALF.best$stock.best <- factor(ALF.best$stock.best, levels = c("LLAT", "SUMM", "ESUM", "ESTU"))
ALF.best$model.best <- factor(ALF.best$model.best, levels = c("D", "TQ", "T", "R","Q","NMA"))
```

and my best attempt at the bar graph.

```
qplot(stock.best, data=ALF.best, geom="bar", weight = value.best, fill=factor(model.best), xlab="", ylab="UH:UE ratio") 
+ scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0.25,0.5,0.75,1,2,3,4)) + coord_flip()
```

This plot is almost perfect, my model transitions line up with the correct values on the axis.  For example in the ESTU factor the transition from model D to model T occurs at 1.18. However, I want my axis to have equal spacing between 0.25 and 1 as from 1 and 4. I can get it artificially by making two graphs one with coord_flip(ylim = c(0.25,1)) and the other with coord_flip(ylim = c(1,4)) and pasting them next to each other, but making it without powerpoint magic would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that your question make sense. Log scales don't make much sense for bar charts since the bar goes to **0**.

Here another version of your weighted bar chart , using `stat_summary`. Personally, I prefer this one because you see what happens really and you have more flexibility ( play with the fun.y for example).

```
  ggplot(data=ALF.best,
       aes(x=stock.best,y=value.best,fill=model.best,group=model.best))+
  geom_bar(stat = "summary",fun.y=sum) + 
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Normally, I'd agree, but this isn't your normal bar chart, and maybe I need something other than a bar chart for what I'm after.  Perhaps it will help if I give more background. I started with 6 models with 14 years of predictive error.  For each year the error is multiplied by a if the error is negative and b if it is positive to determine total cost over those years. I'm plotting the model with the least total cost for each value.best. Value.best is the ratio of a:b, so rather than wanting a bar from 0 (nonsensical) to 4 I want it from 0.25 (a ratio of 0.25:1, to 4:1, with 1:1 in the middle.